# Using awk and sort last column in descending order in Linux

Tags: linux, awk

I have a file contains both name and numbers like :
data.csv

```
2016,Bmw,M2,2 Total score:24

1998,Subaru,Legacy,23 Total score:62

2012,Volkswagen,Golf,59 Total score:28

2001,Dodge,Viper,42 Total score:8

2014,Honda,Accord,83 Total score:112

2015,Chevy,Camaro,0 Total score:0

2008,Honda,Accord,88 Total score:48
```

Total score is last column I did :

```
awk -F","  'NR>1{{for(i=4;i<=6;++i)printf $i""FS }
                                         {sum=0; for(g=8;g<=NF;g++)
                                         sum+=$g
                                         print $i,"Total score:"sum ; print ""}}' data.csv
```

when i try

```
 awk -F","  'NR>1{{for(i=4;i<=6;++i)printf $i""FS }
                                          {sum=0; for(g=8;g<=NF;g++)
                                         sum+=$g
                                          print $i,"Total score:"sum ; print "" | "sort -k1,2n"}}' data.csv
```

It gave me error, I only want to sort total score column, is there anything I did it wrong? Any helps are appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, assuming there are really not blank lined in between each line of data in `data.csv`, all you need is `sort`, you don't need `awk` at all. For example, since there is only `':'` before the total score you want to sort descending by, you can use:

```sh
sort -t: -k2,2rn data.csv
```

Where `-t:` tells sort to use `':'` as the field separator and then the KEYDEF `-k2,2rn` tell sort to use the 2nd field (what's after the `':'` to sort by) and the `rn` says use a *reverse numeric* sort on that field.

**Example Use/Output**

With your data (without blank lines) in `data.csv`, you would have:

```
$ sort -t: -k2,2rn data.csv
2014,Honda,Accord,83 Total score:112
1998,Subaru,Legacy,23 Total score:62
2008,Honda,Accord,88 Total score:48
2012,Volkswagen,Golf,59 Total score:28
2016,Bmw,M2,2 Total score:24
2001,Dodge,Viper,42 Total score:8
2015,Chevy,Camaro,0 Total score:0
```

Which is your sort by `Total score` in descending order. If you want ascending order, just remove the `r` from `-k2,2rn`.

If you do have blank lines, you can remove them before the sort with `sed -i '/^$/d' data.csv`.

**Sorting by number Before "Total score"**

If you want to sort by the number that begins the `XX Total score: yy` field (e.g. `XX`), you can use sort with the field separator being a `','` and then your KEYDEF would be `-k4.1,4.3rn` which just says sort using the 4th field character 1 through character 3 by the same *reverse numeric*, e.g.

```sh
sort -t, -k4.1,4.3rn data.csv
```

**Example Use/Output**

In this case, sorting by the number before `Total score` in descending order would result in:

```
$ sort -t, -k4.1,4.3rn data.csv
2008,Honda,Accord,88 Total score:48
2014,Honda,Accord,83 Total score:112
2012,Volkswagen,Golf,59 Total score:28
2001,Dodge,Viper,42 Total score:8
1998,Subaru,Legacy,23 Total score:62
2016,Bmw,M2,2 Total score:24
2015,Chevy,Camaro,0 Total score:0
```

After posting the original solution I noticed it was ambiguous as which of the numbers on the 4th field you intended to sort on. In either case, here are both solutions. Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: will it follow the same rule if I have to use awk?

Comment: You can use `awk`, and yes, you can follow the same rule breaking on `':'` in the first case and using the 2nd field or on `','` and using the 4th field. But understand, sorting isn't what `awk` does as a tool. I note in your posted command lines that you pipe to `sort` anyway -- there is a reason for that. If you must use `awk`, then just isolate what you will sort by and pipe to `sort`, but know there is really no reason to involve `awk` to begin with (in this case). Other times where separating the field to sort by is impossible, you can use a *Decorate & Sort* technique with `awk`.